# MongoDB authentication failed

Tags: java, mongodb, admin

I am doing some experiments with Java and MongoDB. I have successfully install MongoDB and able to connect through command line. But when I try to connect through Java then it gives me error of authentication. I tried in following way:

```
    nilkash@nilkash-Inspiron-5559:~$ mongo -u admin -p admin123 --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2016-09-17T16:29:31.090+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
>
```

and through Java code:

```
package mongo;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;

/**
 * Java + MongoDB Hello world Example
 *
 */
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
        DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");

        boolean auth = db.authenticate("admin", "admin123".toCharArray());

    if (auth) {

        System.out.println("Login is successful!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Login is failed!");
    }
    System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MongoException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

And got the result for it:

```
Login is failed!
Done
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: You are using the syntax from Mongo Java driver v2. Better switch to Mongo3 syntax (MongoClient and MongoCredentials): http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/ http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.mongodb.MongoCredential

Comment: testdb is wrong, it should be test. Try and let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of MongoDB 3.2, the default authentication mechanism is "SCRAM-SHA-1". There is a separate class available for this authentication. I would recommend using this latest approach.

For more information, please refer this [link](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/connecting/authenticating/).

**Example below:-**

Just the database name, user name, password accordingly in the below code. It should work for you.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential("admin", "admin",
                "admin123".toCharArray());

        mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testdb");

        System.out.println(db.getStats());
        System.out.println(db.getCollectionNames());

        mongoClient.close();
    }
```

Dependency:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**User Creation:-**

```
use admin;

db.createUser({ user : "admin", pwd : "admin123", roles : ["dbAdmin"]});
```

**To check the user details:-**

```
use admin;

db.getUsers();
```

Comment: Hi I tried your solution. But it gives me `'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017` for my username and password. If try with command line `mongo -u admin -p admin123 --authenticationDatabase admin` it works fine.

Comment: @nilkash Try if you can successfully authenticate to Mongo via TCP using [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) tool

Comment: I have updated few commands. Please check whether you have created the user like this. Also, please execute the getUser and let us know the output. I have updated Java code to exactly reflect your user and password details. Please try that. I have created the user using the createUser command and executed the code. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongo -u admin -p admin123 --authenticationDatabase admin
```

You are authenticating to db admin when you try to login using `mongo` shell. But, in code it looks like you are trying to evaluate your login credentials with db testdb

```
DB db = mongo.getDB("testdb");
```

It should be same at both places.

Comment: Hi Astro I am not getting you. can you please explain more.

Comment: For which db the user admin was created?

Answer (score 0):

Since `mongo -u admin -p admin123 --authenticationDatabase admin` seems to be working fine from your comment. Change `DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testdb");` to `DB db = mongoClient.getDB("admin");`

Answer (score 0):

This code works

```
MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(this.username, this.dbname,
                this.password.toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(dbhost, this.dbport), Arrays.asList(mongoCredential));
```